# How to save PDF file in iPhone device through application

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, pdf, nsfilemanager

Currently, I am working on create PDF file, saving it and retrieving file in UIWebview to display through iPhone application.But,Now I want to save PDF file in iPhone device like in NewsStand or iBooks.Is it possible to save PDF file in device? So that, I can open PDF file without opening an application.
Please give me some idea.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven't tried but this can be useful for you:
http://andycodes.tumblr.com/post/738375724/ios4-sdk-opening-pdfs-in-ibooks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSArray *pdfs = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:[paths objectAtIndex:0]] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"pdf" inDirectory:nil];
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is already posted by many. You can Save PDF content which is the URL format like below code

```
NSData *savedPDFFile = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"pdf_url"]]; 
[savedPDFFile writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], @"savedpdffilename.pdf"] atomically:YES];
```

Hope it helps you...!

Answer (score 0):

For sending `PDF File` use [send-bundled-pdf-to-ibooks-from-within-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650263/send-bundled-pdf-to-ibooks-from-within-app). Same is for `newsstand` . **Note** : Firstly save `PDF File` in `directory` then use the `path` to `share`

For `displaying PDF` in own `application` user apple's `QLPreviewController`. check [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DocInteraction/Introduction/Intro.html)

Other `third party` for `free` for `displaying PDF` is :

1. [Reader](https://github.com/vfr/Reader)
2. [FastPDFKit](http://www.fastpdfkit.com/). **Note** : Free version availbale